# Need assistance with changing compression method to CCITT4 in the below python script

Tags: python, image-compression

Here is the sample code to Merge multipage multiple tiff files into a single output file provided as a command line argument to python exe.

```
from PIL import Image
import sys
import os
import subprocess
            
def merge_tiff_files(source_files, outputfile):
    
    images = []
    # clear the images list
    images.clear()
    
    for filename in source_files:
    
        # Open the TIFF image using Pillow
        with Image.open(filename) as img:
            

            # Check if the image has more than one frame (i.e., it is a multi-page TIFF)
            if img.n_frames > 1:
                
                for i in range(img.n_frames):
                    img.seek(i)  # Go to the i-th frame
                    images.append(img.copy().convert('L'))
                
            else:  # If the image has only one frame
                
                # Remove the alpha layer and save the image as a single-page Tiff file
                images.append(img.convert('L'))

    # save the first image as a multi-page TIFF
    images[0].save(outputfile, format='TIFF', save_all=True, append_images=images[1:], compression='packbits')

    # close all images
    for image in images:
        image.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":

    #check for the total command line args
    if len(sys.argv) != 3:
        sys.exit(1)

    if sys.argv[1] != "RANDOM":
        sys.exit(1)

    arguments = sys.argv[2].split("##")

    input_files = arguments[0]

    input_file = input_files.split("+")

    output_file = arguments[1]

    merge_tiff_files( input_file , output_file)
```

Here I have used packbits as compression method instead of it I want to use CCITT4 or Group4 compression method. I tried it in below code but while executing it gives error as return code -2, I guess for grayscale image it is not able to compress it to CCITT4. When tried to convert it to Black & White instead of Gray scale (i.e. images.append(img.copy().convert('1'))) it works but the output file we get is totally inverted in color.

The expected output is in Mono or Gray scale instead of black & white with CCITT4 or Group4 compression method.

Thanks,